# Optimize finding all classes implementing IInterface<T> and those explicitly implementing it with a specific type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, interface, assemblies

I have an interface ISerializeDeserialize defined and some classes inheriting the generic interface. I also have some code generated assemblies using the CodeDomProvider which generates classes inherited from the same interface but implementing it with a specific Type.

What I want to achieve is getting a list of the generic implementations and those implementing the specific type. You can let T=int in the code below.

To get all classes implementing ISerializeDeserialize of some type I so far have this code:

```
private List<Type> GetListOfGenericSerializers()
{
    Type interfaceGenricType = typeof(ISerializeDeserialize<T>);

    var serializers = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                      from genericType in assembly.GetTypes()
                      from interfaceType in genericType.GetInterfaces()
                          .Where(iType => (iType.Name == interfaceGenricType.Name && genericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition))
                      select genericType;

    return serializers.ToList();
}

private List<Type> GetListOfTypeImplementedSerializers()
{
    Type interfaceGenricType = typeof(ISerializeDeserialize<T>);

    var serializers = from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                      from implementedType in assembly.GetTypes()
                      from interfaceType in implementedType.GetInterfaces()
                          .Where(iType => iType == interfaceGenricType)
                      select implementedType;

    return serializers.ToList();
}
```

I could pull them together in one function, but I use two for clarity. Question is, can this be optimized or is it done in a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatly I'm not aware of any other way (I also had to write such code more than once).

The one thing you can do is to make the `Where` in the first method a bit nicer:

```
private List<Type> GetListOfGenericSerializers()
{
  Type interfaceGenricType = typeof(ISerializeDeserialize<>);

  var serializers =
    from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    from genericType in assembly.GetTypes()
    from interfaceType in genericType.GetInterfaces()
    where genericType.IsGenericTypeDefinition &&
          interfaceType.IsGeneric &&
          interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceGenericType
    select genericType;

  return serializers.ToList();
}
```

Comment: It's checking of the .Name property in the first loop which bothers me the most, since it's not 100%. If someone creates another interface with the same name it could match. Guess I could add some logic to check on the FullName instead.

Comment: Added a better version to my answer.

Comment: +1 for answering a question with the word "optimize" in the title with a linq answer.