# How to find all the types in an Assembly that Inherit from a Specific Type C#

Tags: c#, reflection

How do you get a collection of all the types that inherit from a specific other type?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> FindDerivedTypes(Assembly assembly, Type baseType)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
}
```

If you need to handle generics, that gets somewhat trickier (e.g. passing in the open `List<>` type but expecting to get back a type which derived from `List<int>`). Otherwise it's simple though :)

If you want to exclude the type itself, you can do so easily enough:

```
public IEnumerable<Type> FindDerivedTypes(Assembly assembly, Type baseType)
{
    return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t != baseType && 
                                          baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
}
```

Note that this will also allow you to specify an interface and find all the types which implement it, rather than just working with classes as `Type.IsSubclassOf` does.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using this 

Thanks - I ended up using this

        public static List<Type> GetAllSubclassesOf(Type baseType)
        {
            return Assembly.GetAssembly(baseType).GetTypes().
                   Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType)).
                   ToList();
        }

Comment: @Downvoter here. My comment went missing. As indicated by aceinthehole the answer is incorrect. I've added the correct answer as I missed aces comment until I found the code did not work. Merry Christmas.

Comment: @Tim: It's not incorrect, it's slightly different. `IsAssignableFrom` should work as well. In particular, my version copes with interfaces as well. Did you test my code? What case does my answer fail on?

Comment: @Jon: Using LinqPad on Exception your method gives 109 types, my corrected answer gives 108. The reason is your method will include Exception in this result. I believe the question, as I needed, wants what types that inherit from baseType, not the baseType as well.

Comment: @Tim: What does yours give for `IDisposable` for example? If the OP wants to exclude the type itself, it's trivial to do so - I'll edit my answer to add that as an option.

Comment: @Jon. Quite right your method handles interfaces. I'm a VB programmer, we inherit classes and implement interfaces. Is this different in C#? I ask because the question, as I required, wants types that inherit a type not implement a type.

Comment: @Tim: In C# we just use " : " for both... but I would generally consider interfaces as part of the inheritance hierarchy of a type.

Comment: @JonSkeet: is there a similar Linq query for interfaces? The pseudo code I am looking for is `.IsAssignableFrom(IEnumerable)`. I am implementing your suggestion (http://stackoverflow.com/a/298994/837623) and I am somehow stuck in this scenario. Having it within the dictionary (as regular types) might not work as well but I can have a special check just before.

Comment: Using `typeof()` will return the concrete type which I don't care about. The subsequent `Action` is expecting an `IEnumerable<T>` (`int` as a sample)

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: It's not entirely clear what you mean. I suggest you ask a new question with more details. You should be aware that `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` are separate types though.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22860959/c-sharp-switch-between-types-including-interfaces

Comment: According to this answer, a class that implements an interface "derives" from that interface.  I don't think so.

Comment: @HappyNomad: Are you just objecting to the naming of the method?

Comment: @JonSkeet The method's name matches the question, so it's fine. The problem is what the method does when given an interface.

Comment: @HappyNomad: Well the OP never said (4 years ago...) what they'd want to happen for interfaces. Maybe only return interfaces? Maybe return all implementations?

Comment: @JonSkeet That's true. Here's [another idea](http://www.randomhaiku.com/) for what it could return when given an interface. Seriously, though, the OP *did* say, but not specifically.  The OP didn't specifically mention classes, either.

Comment: @HappyNomad: I suggest if you have a better answer, you add it. But I suspect this is what the OP actually wanted, to be honest.

Comment: Since @JonSkeet himself suggested it, I've added [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40238277). The OP seems to indicate that he's not concerned with interfaces.  But we are! ;)

Answer (score 30):

The following method will get a collection of types that inherit a type.

**C#**

```
public IEnumerable<Type> FindSubClassesOf<TBaseType>()
{   
    var baseType = typeof(TBaseType);
    var assembly = baseType.Assembly;

    return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
Public Function FindSubClasses(Of TBaseType)() As IEnumerable(Of Type)

    Dim baseType = GetType(TBaseType)
    Dim assembly = baseType.Assembly

    Return From t In assembly.GetTypes() 
           Where t.IsSubClassOf(baseType) 
           Select t

End Function
```

If you need to include types that implement an interface see @Jon Skeet's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enumerate all types and check for each if it inherits the one you're looking for.

Some code like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262057/optimize-finding-all-classes-implementing-iinterfacet-and-those-explicitly-impl/1265532#1265532) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this method (written for a PCL):

```
public IEnumerable<Type> FindDerivedTypes( Assembly assembly, Type baseType )
{
        TypeInfo baseTypeInfo = baseType.GetTypeInfo();
        bool isClass = baseTypeInfo.IsClass, isInterface = baseTypeInfo.IsInterface;

        return
            from type in assembly.DefinedTypes
            where isClass ? type.IsSubclassOf( baseType ) :
                  isInterface ? type.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains( baseTypeInfo.AsType() ) : false
            select type.AsType();
}
```