# Discovering derived types using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Using reflection, is it possible to discover all types that derive from a given type?

Presumably the scope would be limited to within a single assembly.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

pretty much the same as Darin's but here you go..

```
    public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>()
    {
        return FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)));
    }

    public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly assembly)
    {
        var baseType = typeof(T);
        return assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t =>
                t != baseType &&
                baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                ).ToList();

    }
```

used like:

```
var output = FindAllDerivedTypes<System.IO.Stream>();
            foreach (var type in output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
            }
```

outputs:

```
NullStream
SyncStream
__ConsoleStream
BufferedStream
FileStream
MemoryStream
UnmanagedMemoryStream
PinnedBufferMemoryStream
UnmanagedMemoryStreamWrapper
IsolatedStorageFileStream
CryptoStream
TailStream
```

Comment: I assume you're using `IsAssignableFrom` instead of `IsSubclassOf` to account for interfaces.  But calling it on an interface also returns its implementing classes.

Answer (score 33):

```
var derivedTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                   where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(A))
                   select t;
```

Comment: This is worth mentioning this query only retrieves interfaces or classes that directly derive from the type `A`.

Comment: @ZenLulz The [`IsSubclassOf` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) name is misleading. Actually, it returns `true` for *derived classes*.

Answer (score 13):

```
var types = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(SomeBaseType).IsAssignableFrom(t) && 
                t != typeof(SomeBaseType))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 6):

I rewrote @Hath's excellent answer as an extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static List<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(this Type type)
    {
        return Assembly.GetAssembly(type).GetAllDerivedTypes(type);
    }

    public static List<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(this Assembly assembly, Type type)
    {
        return assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t != type && type.IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var listOfDerived = typeof(MyClass).GetAllDerivedTypes();
```

Comment: Why use [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) instead of [`IsSubclassOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx)?  Maybe you want to support interfaces?  But that result will include implementing classes.

Comment: @HappyNomad You make an excellent point. In my case, I wanted to support interfaces.

Comment: My [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40238277) for a duplicate question supports interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP specified within a single assembly, but since this question is one of the top results when trying to find how to do this I am giving an example of how to do this with all assemblies that derive from the assembly containing the given type.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets all types derived from the given <paramref name="type"/>
/// <para>By default checks the assembly of the given type and all dependent assemblies.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type"></param>
/// <param name="allAssemblies">If false only the assembly containing the type will be checked.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(this Type type, bool allAssemblies = true)
{
    List<Type> derivedTypes = type.GetAllDerivedTypes(Assembly.GetAssembly(type)!).AsList();

    if (allAssemblies)
    {
        IEnumerable<Assembly> dependentAssemblies = GetDependentAssemblies(Assembly.GetAssembly(type)!);
        derivedTypes.AddRange(dependentAssemblies.SelectMany(a => GetAllDerivedTypes(type, a)));
    }

    return derivedTypes;
}

private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetDependentAssemblies(Assembly analyzedAssembly)
{
    return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(a => a.GetReferencedAssemblies()
            .Select(assemblyName => assemblyName.FullName)
            .Contains(analyzedAssembly.FullName));
}

private static IEnumerable<Type> GetAllDerivedTypes(this Type baseType, Assembly assembly)
{
    TypeInfo baseTypeInfo = baseType.GetTypeInfo();

    return assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(type =>
    {
        if (baseTypeInfo.IsClass)
        {
            return type.IsSubclassOf(baseType);
        }

        return baseTypeInfo.IsInterface && type.ImplementedInterfaces.Contains(baseTypeInfo.AsType());

    }).Select(type => type.AsType());
}
```