# Reflection - check for parent class

Tags: c#, reflection

How do I check if class inherits from my class DataSource (abstract class).

here is what I got:

```
var q = from t in Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("DefaultDataSources")).GetTypes()
                where t.IsClass
                select t;
```

I don't know what condition to add :(

Comment: The code you present does not seem to have anything to do with the problem you are asking about. Have you tried using the [`Type.BaseType` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type.basetype)?

Comment: You can use [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to check if a type inherits from another type (or implements an interface) but I'm not sure how you'd do it in LINQ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
var query = Assembly.Load(...)
                    .GetTypes()
                    .Where(t => typeof(DataSource).IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

(The `IsAssignableFrom` part is the interesting bit, but I gave the full query as this is a good example of a case where a query expression just gets in the way - a single call to the `Where` extension method is simpler.)

Answer (score 2):

IsAssignableFrom().

This link shows the reverse process - discovering all the derivations of a base class.

[Discovering derived types using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection)