# Get a Collection of all Objects that derive from a base class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app that contains a lot of pages that need to be added to a report. The number of pages grows quickly so I want to be able to populate the report with them dynamically. The methods below return the list of pages correctly but I cant get it to add the page to the report.

I get Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'Reports.Pages.PageBase' How can I correct this?

```
private void AddAllPages()
        {
            var pages = FindSubClassesOf<PageBase>();

            foreach (var pg in pages)
            {
              Report.Pages.Add(pg);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<Type> FindSubClassesOf<TBaseType>()
        {
            var baseType = typeof(TBaseType);
            var assembly = baseType.Assembly;

            return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseType));
        }
```

Comment: Confusing types and objects is rather a problem, the kind that requires a book, not an SO answer.  There's no concrete advise to give here, creating an object of the types you found isn't going to give you a nicely ordered report at all.  You'll have to think this through.

Comment: The report object knows how to handle the pages it is given. So the order of the pages is not important. Just adding the pages to the report is the goal here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an instance of each type:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

If the types do not have default constructors, you will need to pass constructor arguments too.

Comment: so using this example it would be

private void AddAllPages()
        {
            var pages = FindSubClassesOf<PageBase>();

            foreach (var pg in pages)
            {
              var newpage = Activator.CreateInstance(pg);
              Report.Pages.Add(newpage);
            }
        }

is this correct?

Comment: @RobertMeier: Yes, except that `pg` is a misleading name.  It's actually a type.

Comment: Excelent. I will give this a try in the morning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Discovering derived types using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection)

```
public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>()
{
    return FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)));
}

public static List<Type> FindAllDerivedTypes<T>(Assembly assembly)
{
    var derivedType = typeof(T);
    return assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(t =>
            t != derivedType &&
            derivedType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
            ).ToList();

}
```