# Creating instances of specified inherited types

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class named module in Modules class library.

```
public class Module{}
```

And implementations like this.

```
public class ModuleA: Module{...}
public class ModuleB: Module{...}
public class ModuleC: Module{...}
```

I want to create a class that will create instances and give me a list that inherited from `Module` class.

```
public class ModulesFactory{
  public IList<Module> GetModules(){
   ???????
   ???????
  }
}
```

I could not select inherited calsses in class library.

Comment: List inherited from Module, or List of Module inheritants?

Comment: You need to scan the assemblies where you expect the module class would be inherited.

Comment: You can get the types inherited Module by using IsAssignableFrom, see this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection

Comment: **Possible duplicate**
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection

Comment: I think the generic type of IList<Module> would refer to the Module in the reflection namespace... I'd put the baseclass of the Module in a Project which is referenced by both the assembly containing the factory and the modules library... then you have the basetype and can return a IList<ModuleBase> without problems (I'd rename it so it does not get mixxed up with the reflection namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can create a generic method like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TModule> GetModules<TModule>()
    {
        var moduleType = typeof (TModule);

        var dependencyModuleTypes = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(moduleType)).Select(p=>(TModule)Activator.CreateInstance(p));

        return dependencyModuleTypes;
    }
```

if Assembly selection is current assembly?

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear to me if you have a static list or only know the names of you classes. Why can't you just use new ModuleA() and add it to as List that you return?

If you only know the names you could use the [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method.

If both suggestions don't work, you will have to explain your problem in more detail, please.

Sascha