# How to identify derived classes that is going to affect when base class is modified

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, superclass

If I modified base class, how can I know that which derived classes are affected. To elaborate more, for example, I have two base classes named Class A and Class B. I have Class X and Class Y inheriting from Class A, and Class Z inherits from Class B. Here in this case scenario, I have only 2 base class and 3 derived classes and it is manageable to see how they are interrelated. What if I have so many derived classes with so many base classes in real world enterprise application. How can I identify which classes are going to affect when I change base class. Thank.

Comment: Via your documentation and class diagrams?  Or do you mean via code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282377/visual-studio-how-do-i-show-all-classes-inherited-from-a-base-class

Comment: @cjb110 I agree that class diagrams is one way to go. Is is possible by code to look up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you would right click on the thing you want to change and in the popup menu select either `View all references` or `View call hierarchy`.

If you want to do it yourself in code you would use `reflection` for example as described in [Discovering derived types using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection).

Comment: Thank. That's what I want.