# Use reflection to get private fields on all subclasses?

Tags: c#, reflection, private

I tried

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But this will only return protected fields, this code is declared on the base class, the private field is declared in a derived class, if I make this field protected, it gets returned...

Comment: Well, you're not executing the code on the subclass, you're executing the code on the base class.  Polymorphism doesn't play a part here; that's *method overriding.*  Try executing your code on an instance of the derived class.

Comment: So its not possible to get private members of other classes in the hierarchy?

Comment: Try [identifying your derived types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection) first, then execute your `GetFields` method on each derived type.