# Switch between types including interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

I have a set of overloads for a `get` function. Each one have a different input type but basically the same signature schema (as follow):

```
string GetPropertyValue(int propId, string defaultValue)
bool GetPropertyValue(int propId, bool defaultValue)
int GetPropertyValue(int propId, int defaultValue)
IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyValue(int propId, IEnumerable<string> defaultValues)
IEnumerable<bool> GetPropertyValue(int propId, IEnumerable<bool> defaultValues)
IEnumerable<int> GetPropertyValue(int propId, IEnumerable<int> defaultValues)
```

I am working on simplifying the API into a single generic method (as follow):

```
T GetPropertyValue<T>(int propId , T defaultValue)
```

To implement such method, I tried to switch on the type on the default value using a dictionary ([inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298994/837623)):

```
var actionDico = new Dictionary<Type, System.Action>
{
    /* since the type of `defaultValue` is `T`, I cannot use `(bool)defaultValue` for example
       therefore casting to (object) before to escape Cast operator restriction.
       Will not fail as the key of the dictionary is a matching type */
    {typeof(bool), () => dob.GetPropertyValue(propId, (bool)(object)defaultValue)},
    {typeof(int), () => dob.GetPropertyValue(propId, (int)(object)defaultValue)},
    {typeof(string), () => dob.GetPropertyValue(propId, (string)(object)defaultValue)}
}
```

With concrete types, the previous implementation is perfectly fine (at least in my case). The call will be done using `actionDico[typeof(T)]();`.

Having the following within the dictionary is fine:

```
{typeof(IEnumerable<int>), () => dob.GetPropertyValue(propId, (IEnumerable<int>)(object)defaultValue)},
```

But the call is usually done using an object which implement `IEnumerable<int>` (like `List<int>`). In such case calling `actionDico[typeof(T)]();` is looking for `List<int>` within the keys collection, not `IEnumerable<int>`.

I am trying to avoid reflection (and will keep it as last resort). Is there a way similar to `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` method for interfaces? In other words, I want to check wether the provided type implements `IEnumerable<int>` rather than being it.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to *do* with the dictionary, or what the "Cast operator restriction" you're talking about is. Note that you can use `typeof(IEnumerable<int>)` perfectly easily - where does `List<T>` come into this at all? (The *only* mention of `List<T>` is in the explanation of why you don't want to use `typeof` - nowhere in the example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: please have a look at the edit

Comment: It is equivalent to `actionDico[defaultValue.GetType()]`.  Sure, you get List<> and not the IEnumerable<>.  So the dictionary is not useful, you have to enumerate the types to find a match.  You are certainly stuck with IsAssignableFrom(), it is not that expensive.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: What does `typeof(defaultValue)` even mean? In what way is `defaultValue` the name of a type? It's still *very* unclear how you're using the type.

Comment: @HansPassant: I tried to use it but it does not accept interfaces. I get `Interface name is not valid at this point` as error. I tried `if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(IEnumerable<int>))`

Comment: @JonSkeet: Just a typo, I fixed it. I mean `typeof(T)`. `T` is the type of `defaultValue`. Depending on the type of the default value, the specific method should be called.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: That's just a matter of using `IsAssignableFrom` the wrong way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't look the type up in the dictionary that way. You'll have to loop through the key-value pairs:

```
Type targetType = defaultValue.GetType();
foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
    if (pair.Key.IsAssignableFrom(targetType))
    {
        // Use pair.Value
    }
}
```

However, at this point you've effectively just got a `List<Tuple<Type, Action>>` rather than a dictionary, in terms of how you're using it... So you could instead use:

```
List<Tuple<Type, Action>> actions = new List<Tuple<Type, Action>>
{
    Tuple.Create(typeof(bool), () => dob.GetPropertyValue(propId, (bool) (object)defaultValue),
    Tuple.Create(typeof(int), () => dob.GetPropertyValue(propId, (int) (object)defaultValue),
    // etc
};
```

... and then just use `Item1` and `Item2` in the loop earlier.

Comment: That looks like a dump mistake now :) Thank you! Also if possible could you please elaborate a bit on your last comment? I did not quite got what you are pointing to

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: I've added an example. Basically dictoinaries are good for key/value lookup, but you can't actually look up by a key in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [as operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)

```
var isEnumerable = defaultValue as IEnumerable;
if (isEnumerable != null)
{

}
```